# visual studio 2012 - class diagram and aggregation

Tags: visual-studio-2012, class-diagram

I am using visual studio 2012 ultimate and I wanted to use built-in feature to create class diagrams.

The thing is, when I click on one of my projects there is an option `view class diagram`.

Now I can see my classes but when I open the toolbox I can only use things from category `Class Designer`, so for relationships I can only use Inheritance and Association and the group called `UML Class Diagram` is greyed out.

Is it possible to "enable" in some way those other relationship options? Or do I need to create modelling project for my diagrams to use `UML Class Diagram` options?

Answer (score 1):

Press right mouse button on a class element and select from the context menu "Add" menu item. You will find more relations there.